# Implementing a tensorflow graph into a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to implement roughly the following architecture in Keras (preferably) or Tensorflow.

```
          ___________      _________      _________     ________    ______
          | Conv    |     | Max    |     | Dense  |    |       |   |     |
Input0--> | Layer 1 | --> | Pool 1 | --> | Layer  | -->|       |   |     |
          |_________|     |________|     |________|    | Sum   |   | Out |
                                                       | Layer |-->|_____|
Input1    ----------- Converted to trainable weights-->|       |              
                                                       |_______|                                                                               |_______|
```

In short, it is pretty much a model with two inputs, merged into one output using an Add([input0, input1]) layer. The trick is that one of the inputs must be seen as a variable = trainable weight.

Keras layer Add() does not allow this, and it takes input0 and input1 as non-trainable variables:

```
input0    = Input((28,28,1))
x         = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)(mod1)
x         = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input0)
x         = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x         = Flatten()(x)
x         = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

input1    = Input((128,))

x         = Add()([x, input1])
x         = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model     = Model(inputs = [mod1,TPM], outputs = x)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I can implement a graph in tensorflow that adds a placeholder X with a weight b, and learns the value for b in respect to a target Y.

```
train_X = numpy.asarray([1.0, 2.0])
train_Y = numpy.asarray([0.0, 2.5])
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
b = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.0], name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(X, b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - train_Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)

train = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
#init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for step in range(epochs):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
```

Ths works exaclty how I want. Simple optimizable addition of an input and weights. But I can't include this into a Keras model.I am missing the step how to merge both ideas.

How can I include a layer that only sums one trainable tensor to a non-trainable tensor?

Comment: It seems that you want to initialize a variable which will be added to the output of your first dense layer. That sounds similar (though not exactly the same) to just initialize the bias of your first dense layer with a constant like [0.0, 0.0]. Will this fits what you want?

Comment: @Y.Luo This is I think in essence what I want, but a Dense layer wont add the bias element-wise, as with increasing units, the Dense layer adds the bias to all combinations of inputs. Besides, I do not want the multiplication weights 'W' from a normal Dense layer. I tried unsuccesfully to implement it that way, but the permutations of the inputs and the multiplicative matrix W of the Dense layer made it impossible...

Comment: @Y.Luo I modified the drawing of the architecture, to make clear that the sum layer does not have to be nor replace the Dense layer. The input1 does behave like a bias, namely just an additive factor, but the layer does not behave like a Dense layer.

Comment: Is writing a custom layer a viable option for your case?

Comment: @Y.Luo yes! I would love a solution that involves a custom layer. I have tried that but without success. In Keras the custom layers inherit methods that interfere (from Dense layers, same problem as above), and how to include custom layers from tensorflow into a Keras model would answer the question perfectly.

Comment: I saw your previous comments to my answer and didn't have time to respond to it. I just found that you deleted it. Just to check, do you have your problem solved?

Comment: @Y.Luo Yes I was asking about dynamically accessing the weights of the custom layer (reason why I included it in the drawing as an external input), but this is of course easily done with the inherited methods get and set_weights. With that all seems resolved. I had written the same code for the Keras custom layer but had not worked out. Your answer seems to work for me right now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to know. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your needs. Based on your tensorflow code, I don't think you will have to feed in the initial value. In that case, I hope the following is at least close to what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Add

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, bias_init, **kwargs):
        self.bias_init = bias_init
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bias = self.add_weight(name='bias',
                                    shape=input_shape[1:],
                                    initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(self.bias_init),
                                    trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        return x + self.bias

input0    = Input((28,28,1))
x         = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1))(input0)
x         = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input0)
x         = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x         = Flatten()(x)
x         = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

input1    = np.random.rand(128)

x         = MyLayer(input1)(x)
x         = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model     = Model(inputs=input0, outputs=x)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```