# How to integrate a keras model to a tensorflow network

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to integrate a keras trained model to a tensorflow network to help training the tensorflow model, i.e., the keras model need not to be trained again, it just generate a loss for tensorflow model. The following graph is the basic network architecture.
[image]

The follow code is to generate the loss for keras model. But, unfortunately, it failed to load the pretrained keras model, though it didn’t give any error. i.e., the code can work, but it just loaded a random model(random value of variable), it returned a random value, not the value generate by the pretrained model.

```
def keras_loss(sess,prediction):
  #import package
  from keras.models import Model
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,InputLayer
  from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
  from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import preprocess_input  
  from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
  from keras import backend as K

  K.set_session(sess)  #sess is the tensorflow model
  K.set_learning_phase(False)
  base_model = InceptionResNetV2 (input_shape=(None, None, 3), include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=None)
  x = Dropout(0.75)(base_model.output)
  x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

  model = Model(base_model.input, x) #load the pretrained model
  model.load_weights('./inception_resnet_weights.h5')
  score = model(prediction)  #prediction is a tf tensor

  return score
```

I read the related instruction on stackoverflow:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfdYY.png)  [Calling a Keras model on a TensorFlow tensor but keep weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790506/calling-a-keras-model-on-a-tensorflow-tensor-but-keep-weights) 
[2][Tensorflow op in Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067108/tensorflow-op-in-keras-model)
[3][Implementing a tensorflow graph into a Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120251/implementing-a-tensorflow-graph-into-a-keras-model)

But it still can’t solve my problem.Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you still get random weights if you load weights in InceptionResNetV2 with the keywordargument: weights='imagenet'?

Answer (score 0):

From the keras [docs](https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionresnetv2):

> weights: one of None (random initialization) or 'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet).

You want to use `weights='imagenet'` instead of `None`.

Comment: The model to load is our fine-tuned model 'inception_resnet_weights.h5', not the default model on website. If I use `weights='imagenet'`,it generates the an URL error.